# how can act fractional operator on kets?

Tags: operators

Knowing $\hat{A}\left|ψ\right\rangle$ and $\hat{B}\left|ψ\right\rangle$ , how to find answer of ($\hat{A}+\hat{B} )^ {1/2} \left|ψ\right\rangle $

Note : may $\hat{A}$ and  $\hat{B}$ are not in the form of tensors.

Comment: Do $A$ and $B$ commute?  Are they positive?

Comment: In general, square root of an operator is not unique, see e.g. [this discussion of Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Making_the_Schr.C3.B6dinger_equation_relativistic).

Comment: @ValterMoretti wt matter??

Comment: What do you mean *"may $A$ and $B$ are not in the form of tensors"*? Why do you not know how to find $(A+B)^{1/2}$? If you can write down $(A+B)^{1/2}$ without having to ask what it means, that means that you defined it somehow. What about applying the definition does not give you the result you want?

Comment: If A+B is not self-adjoint and positive $(A+B)^{1/2}$ is not defined...

Comment: @ValterMoretti thnk you!

Comment: @ACuriousMind not knowing tensor form of them:))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to expand $(\hat A+\hat B)^{1/2}$ in terms of a Taylor series. This holds in general. Let us say you wanted to find:
$$f(\hat A)| \psi \rangle$$
then you have to expand $f(\hat A)$ in terms of a Taylor series, so in your specific case we can write it as $(\hat A+\hat B-\hat I+\hat I)^{1/2}$ where $\hat I$ is the identity operator. Expanding this we get:
$$(\hat A+\hat B-\hat I+\hat I)^{1/2}=\hat I+\frac{1}{2}(\hat A+\hat B-\hat I)-\frac{1}{8}(\hat A+\hat B-\hat I)^2+...$$
And thus:
$$(\hat A+\hat B)^{1/2}|\psi \rangle=\left(\hat I+\frac{1}{2}(\hat A+\hat B-\hat I)-\frac{1}{8}(\hat A+\hat B-\hat I)^2+...\right)|\psi \rangle$$
Which depending on your values of $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ may be easy or hard to do.

Comment: Note that this has a limited radius of convergence due to branch point of square root at zero.